Equation of motion for free fall body with air resistance
I want to derive the equation of motion for the an average skydiver free falling to earth with air resistance, most the solution online doesn't use the drag force formula to avoid making the problem harder (making the the equation non linear)
So, can some help me to solve this first order nonlinear diffrential equation
70(dV/dt) + 0.07686V^2 - 686.7 = 0
Or in general term
m(dV/dt) + 0.5pACDv^2 - mg = 0

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

To derive the solution to this first-order nonlinear differential equation that represents the motion of a skydiver falling with air resistance let's first of fall look at the equation and define the variables
$m \frac{dV}{dt} + 0.5 \, p \, A \, C_D \, V^2 - mg = 0$
where:
$m$ is the mass of the skydiver,
$V$ is the velocity of the skydiver,
$g$ is the acceleration due to gravity,
$p$ is the air density,
$A$ is the cross-sectional area of the skydiver,
$C_D$ is the drag coefficient.
This equation can also be written as:
$\frac{dV}{dt} = \frac{mg - 0.5 \, p \, A \, C_D \, V^2}{m}$
My Solution Strategy
To solve this nonlinear differential equation, I will use separation of variables. Define the terminal velocity $V_t$ as the velocity at which the gravitational force is balanced by the drag force:
$mg = 0.5 \, p \, A \, C_D \, V_t^2 \Rightarrow V_t = \sqrt{\frac{2mg}{p A C_D}}$
Substitute this in the equation:
$\frac{dV}{dt} = g \left(1 - \frac{V^2}{V_t^2}\right)$
This form is separable, so we can rewrite it as:
$\frac{dV}{1 - \frac{V^2}{V_t^2}} = g \ dt$
Now, we have to solve the integral on both sides.
First Separate the variables:
$\int \frac{1}{1 - \frac{V^2}{V_t^2}} \, dV = \int g \ dt$
I will use the substitution $V = V_t \tanh(k)$, which simplifies the integral due to the properties of hyperbolic functions I think you know.:
After solving, we find:
$V = V_t \tanh \left(\frac{gt}{V_t}\right)$
Therefore The velocity $V$ of the skydiver as a function of time $t$ is given by:
$V(t) = V_t \tanh \left(\frac{gt}{V_t}\right)$
This solution describes the velocity approaching terminal velocity $V_t$ as time goes on.

Amazing, nice work, thanks very much for the answer.

The equation of motion is,
$m \frac{dv}{dt}+0.5pACDv^2=mg$ naming $k=0.5pACD$
Then the equation of motion is ,
$m \frac{dv}{dt}+kv^2=mg \Rightarrow m \frac{dv}{dt}=mg-kv^2 \Rightarrow \frac{m \frac{dv}{dt}}{mg-kv^2}=1$ Equation 1
We can say that because $mg-kv^2 >0$ , the parachutist initially increases his fall speed and finally it tends to fall with a limiting speed.
we can integrate both members of equation 1 from zero to time T
$ \int _0^T \frac{m \frac{dv}{dt}}{mg-kv^2} \ dt=\int_0^T \ dt \Rightarrow m \int_{v(0)}^{v(T)} \ \frac{1}{mg-kv^2} \ dv=T$
but $v(0)=0 $ then for the first integral use the method of simple fractions
$\frac{1}{mg-kv^2}=\frac{A}{\sqrt{mg}+\sqrt{k} \ v}+\frac{B}{\sqrt{mg}-\sqrt{k} \ v} \Rightarrow A=B=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{mg}}$
i think you can continue ...
